# Error when transfer at token contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm building a token smart contract And I am using ropsen tesnet with remix.

When I call the function *transfer* or *transferfrom* I always got error:
on **ropsen tesnet** I got:

> transact to TokenERC20.transfer errored: VM error: revert. revert The
>   transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The
>   constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction
>   to get more information.

on **JavaScript JM** I got the same error while I can debug,and my debug information is:

> **status**    0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed
>   **from**  0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c
>   **to**    TokenERC20.transfer(address,uint256) 0xbbf289d846208c16edc8474705c748aff07732db
>   **gas**   3000000 gas
>
> **transaction cost**    23644 gas
>   **execution cost**    772     0x6581192b9d4c2395814668bb13163f0a6c34bab8f49b8395950b278ed7e9c666 
>   gas   hash input   ...
>   decoded input     {   "address _to":
>   "0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c",     "uint256 _value": "100"
>   }  decoded output     {}  logs    []  value   0 wei

Here is my coding:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract TokenERC20 {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;  // decimals 可以有的小数点个数，最小的代币单位。18 是建议的默认值
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    // 用mapping保存每个地址对应的余额
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    // 存储对账号的控制
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // 事件，用来通知客户端交易发生
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // 事件，用来通知客户端代币被消费
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * 初始化构造
     */
    function TokenERC20(uint256 initialSupply, string tokenName, string tokenSymbol) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // 供应的份额，份额跟最小的代币单位有关，份额 = 币数 * 10 ** decimals。
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // 创建者拥有所有的代币
        name = tokenName;                                   // 代币名称
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // 代币符号
    }

    /**
     * 代币交易转移的内部实现
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // 确保目标地址不为0x0，因为0x0地址代表销毁
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // 检查发送者余额
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // 确保转移为正数个
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);

        // 以下用来检查交易，
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

        // 用assert来检查代码逻辑。
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     *  代币交易转移
     * 从自己（创建交易者）账号发送`_value`个代币到 `_to`账号
     *
     * @param _to 接收者地址
     * @param _value 转移数额
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * 账号之间代币交易转移
     * @param _from 发送者地址
     * @param _to 接收者地址
     * @param _value 转移数额
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * 设置某个地址（合约）可以创建交易者名义花费的代币数。
     *
     * 允许发送者`_spender` 花费不多于 `_value` 个代币
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * 设置允许一个地址（合约）以我（创建交易者）的名义可最多花费的代币数。
     *
     * @param _spender 被授权的地址（合约）
     * @param _value 最大可花费代币数
     * @param _extraData 发送给合约的附加数据
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            // 通知合约
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 销毁我（创建交易者）账户中指定个代币
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * 销毁用户账户中指定个代币
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you include the parameters you used when deploying? I just tested and it worked fine. I deployed under the JS VM using account 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c sending ("9999999999999999999999","NAME","N") to the constructor. Then called `transfer("0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c",10)`. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the transfer function use the *payable* keyword if you are wanting the contract to accept ether.

Comment: The `transfer` function is working with tokens, not ether. The `payable` keyword is not needed.

Comment: True, sorry I misinterpreted the question. From what i can see, the contract is fine as it is essentially the basic token template.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put any Ether when calling `transfer` function, just set the `value` field of your transaction to `0`.